# SQL to determine which rows to retain and which to remove

Tags: pdf, ssis, row, ssms, charindex

Good Morning Everyone,

I am having a bit of a mental block and was going to see if anyone can help me. I have a table that inventories PDF Files that our office creates. We have changed the naming convention and I am trying to develop logic that specifies when a PDF with the new naming convention has been created to tag the old one so that I can develop a batch script to move them out of the files location. Below are some examples. Each file is its own row in the table by the way.

```
     PAR                          ORIGFILENAME

 111100000012         |          1100000012.pdf

 111100000012         |          1100000012_C_1_UB.pdf

 111100000012         |          1100000012_R_1.pdf
```

The new naming convention contains _R_Number or _C_Number. In the above example The first file is old and I want to retain the second 2.

A second example that has a bit more. Below are 5 files. I want to retain the last two that have the new naming convention and remove the top 3.

```
    PAR                           ORIGFILENAME

 1100000076                      1100000076-2.pdf

 1100000076                      1100000076-3.pdf

 1100000076                      1100000076.pdf

 1100000076                      1100000076_C_7_BARN.pdf

 1100000076                      1100000076_R_1.pdf
```

My plans if I can key on these old files when a new one exists is to develop those names into a batch script and incorporate it into a SSIS package that will run weekly to keep our PDF repository clean. I appreciate any help and incite.

Comment: Presumably since you mention SSIS you're using SQL Server, if so please TAG appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work, although a more varied amount of sample data would be useful.

The following uses an updatable CTE to identify the old/new format names and deletes the old format where the same PAR has a new format

```
with f as (
  select *,
    case when OrigFilename like '%*_%' escape '*' then 0 else 1 end del
  from t
)
delete from f
where del=1 
  and exists (select * from f f2 where f2.par=f.par and f2.del=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to highlight the records you want to remove - and you only want to return the records in the old format, when both a C_7 and R_1 record exists, maybe something like this?

```
;WITH c_7_records AS (
      SELECT par
        FROM my_table
       WHERE origfilename LIKE '%_C_7_%'
), 
r_1_records AS (
      SELECT par
        FROM my_table
       WHERE origfilename LIKE '%_R_1%'
), 
records_to_remove AS (
      SELECT 
    DISTINCT mt.origfilename
        FROM my_table AS mt
        JOIN c_7_records AS cr ON mt.par = cr.par
        JOIN r_1_records AS rr ON mt.par = rr.par
       WHERE mt.origfilename NOT LIKE '%_C_7_%'
         AND mt.origfilename NOT LIKE '%_R_1%'
)
SELECT * FROM records_to_remove;
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/795db0/2/0)